# Will combining the same two Muppets in Harv-E always give me the same result?

Tags: my-muppets-show

I am too cheap to pay the Diamonds to find out the combinations to get specific Muppets for my stage, so I am just combining Muppets in order to find out which combinations give me which Muppets. I am assuming one comibnation, when repeated, will always give me the same Muppet, but is this actually the case?

Comment: What is this game and why aren't I playing it?

Answer (score -2):

**Yes and No**

Yes, all the combinations seem to be the same, but there is always a chance that it will fail to give you its intended Muppet.

That being said, since it is always the same outcome (for the most part), there are a [number](http://digitizemyshow.com/2013/08/muppet-combination-codes/) [of](http://www.writerparty.com/party/my-muppets-show-iosandroid-muppet-combination-list-how-to-get-every-muppet-from-harv-e/) [guides](http://www.gamerevolution.com/cheats/my-muppets-show) that can show what the combinations are...

If you would rather figure them out by trial and error, by all means! Just don't waste your diamonds trying to do it.

Comment: Why the downvote?